# Call a function from background within web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to upgrade my Google Chrome extension.

I need to call a function which is located in background script. But how to do it when I want to call it from web page?

For example, user opens any site and clicks a button. I then want to pass some data to background script from web page, and then from background to web page.

Basically what I'm trying to do is `XMLHttpRequest` from background and push results back to web page, but because Google Chrome has origin security where protocols, domains, and ports must match, it is blocking the `XMLHttpRequest`.

But I want to do it that way. Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Search jquery Ajax and you'll get everything you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) for that.